# MySQL REGEXP to find a word and then non-comma characters till end line

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like a MySQL regexp pattern that looks at comma separated names and results in 1/True if all the names have to deal with Covid labs, but 0/False if they do not. Some examples below with expected behavior:

```
SET @pattern = 'some regexp pattern'
-- example 1:
SELECT 'COVID-19 Positive Lab Results' REGEXP @pattern;
>>> 1

--example 2:
SELECT 'COVID-19 Positive Lab Results, Traveling Test, COVID-19 Pending Lab Results REGEXP @pattern;
>>> 0

--example 3:
SELECT 'COVID-19 Positive Lab Results, COVID-19 Pending Lab Result - ABC'
REGEXP @pattern;
>>> 1
```

The pattern I have so far is `'(covid.*[lab|test].*,)*.*covid.*[lab|test]([^,])+$'`

My thinking was that `(covid.*[lab|test].*,)*` would find 0 or any uninterrupted number of entries that have to deal with covid lab/test results and then I would require it with `.*covid.*[lab|test]([^,])+$` to end with a Covid lab result pattern. Neither part is working right now:

the first one returns 1 for:
`'COVID-19 Positive Lab Results, Traveling Test, COVID-19 Pending Lab Results, COVID-19 test'`

and the second one returns 1 for:
`'COVID-19 Positive Lab Results, ab'`

Solution doesn't have to be regex to be clear

Comment: Are you looking for `^[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*(,[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*)*$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does work for all the examples I am testing against. Thanks for the help! Could you help me understand why switching from `[lab|test]` to `(lab|test)` was part of what made this work? Thanks gain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*(,[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*)*$
```

*Details*

- `^`  - start of string
- `[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma, `covid` substring, zero or more chars other than a comma, `lab` or `test`, zero or more chars other than a comma
- `(,[^,]*covid[^,]*(lab|test)[^,]*)*` - zero or more sequences of a comma, zero or more chars other than a comma, `covid` substring, zero or more chars other than a comma, `lab` or `test`, zero or more chars other than a comma
- `$` - end of string.

One of the problems was the fact that you used a [bracket expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[...]`) instead of a [grouping construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (`(...)`).